# Function isn't working in C++

Tags: c++, function

I have a problem with the program below from the line #42 to line #47,
 the program should output the average of each student , but it gave NaN instead of the average.

Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int students = 3;
const int exams = 4;
int minimum( int [ ][ exams ], int, int );
int maximum( int [ ][ exams ], int, int );
double average( int [ ], int );
void printArray( int [ ][ exams ], int, int );
int main()
{
int studentGrades[ students ][ exams ] = { { 77, 68, 86, 73 }, { 96, 87, 89, 78 },
{ 70, 90, 86, 81 } };
cout << "The array is:\t";
printArray( studentGrades, students, exams );
cout << "\n\nThe highest grade is "<< maximum( studentGrades,students,exams) <<endl;
cout << "The lowest grade is "<< minimum( studentGrades,students,exams) <<endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision( 2 );
for ( int person = 0; person < students; person++ )
cout << "\nThe average grade for student " << person<< " is "<< average( studentGrades[ person ], exams );
return 0;
}
int minimum( int grades[][ exams ], int pupils, int tests )
{
int lowGrade = 100; // initialize to highest possible grade
for ( int i = 0; i < pupils; i++ )
for ( int j = 0; j < tests; j++ )
if ( grades[ i ][ j ] < lowGrade )
lowGrade = grades[ i ][ j ];
return lowGrade;
}
int maximum( int grades[][ exams ], int pupils, int tests )
{
int highGrade = 0; // initialize to lowest possible grade
for ( int i = 0; i < pupils; i++ )
for ( int j = 0; j < tests; j++ )
if ( grades[ i ][ j ] > highGrade )
highGrade = grades[ i ][ j ];
return highGrade;
}

double average( int setOfGrades[], int tests ) // here was a problem the output of the average is NaN
{
int total = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < tests; i++ )
total += setOfGrades[ i ];
total=total/tests;
}
void printArray( int grades[][ exams ], int pupils, int tests )
{
cout << left << " [0]  [1]  [2]  [3]";
for ( int i = 0; i < pupils; i++ ) {
    cout << "\nstudentGrades[" << i << "] ";
for ( int j = 0; j < tests; j++ )
cout << setw( 5 ) << grades[ i ][ j ];
}
}
```

Comment: You need to break the problem down into smaller parts, and test your assumptions. All the input/output code is distracting. Focus on the core calculation. Test it on its own. Write a function to pass example data and check the results are what you expect.

Comment: Hi Abo, don't plead with people to upvote your post. Instead, [edit] it and improve it as suggested in the [MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/155826). When you make improvements, people will see the post and may upvote it. As Peter suggests, try narrowing down the problem. How about highlighting the lines in question instead of making us have to count them? What about indenting your code properly so it's readable? There's a lot you can do here to help get on the right track. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return your total...

```
double average( int setOfGrades[], int tests ) 
{
   int total = 0;
   for ( int i = 0; i < tests; i++ )
   {
      total += setOfGrades[ i ];
    }
    total=total/tests;
   return total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget `return` the value, and it's better to calculate the average by `double`:

```
double average( int setOfGrades[], int tests )
{
  double total = 0; <------------------------- double

  ...

  return total; <----------------------------- return the value
}
```